# Add Quotation marks to :before and :after elements

Tags: html, css

I've tried adding `"`to the `content: ""`to achieve quotations. This resulted in the css being ignored. I've tried wrapping the " in single quotes, `content: '"'`Same result. CSS is ignored

I've tried `content: "&ldquo;"`but the letters are rendered.

How can I render Quotation marks in :before and :after CSS pseudo elements? I would prefer not to use `background-image: url('http://url.com')` so that I can use font size to scale the quotation marks, and users can copy the quotes.

```
.review-wrapper h2:before {
    content: "&ldquo;";
    position: absolute;
    width: 15%;
    height: 1px;
    bottom: 30px;
    left: 42%;
}
```

Comment: Check out this article for more about the cool things you can do with :before and :after content - https://css-tricks.com/css-content/

Comment: Are you sure? `content: '"';` works fine in the [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/j3c4pv7k/).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to unicode-escape the content property like this:

```
content: "\0022";
```

http://codepen.io/MattDiMu/pen/jryOQj

Comment: Works! Thanks man :)

Comment: @Zaeo feel free to mark it as answer plz :)

Comment: Had a limit for me to accept as answer, was too new a question :)

Comment: that's not the same quotation mark as ldquo

Answer (score 2):

You can just escape the quotation mark:

```
.review-wrapper h2:before {
    content: "\""
}
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/g7eyq5zg/